# gdb Info manual

Tags: documentation, info, gdb, manual

I can't seem to find the gdb Info manual file on the [gnu.org documentation page for gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/), which only seems to have a PDF version and an online version. I've found and manually installed several other Info manuals from GNU before, but can't seem to find one for gdb. Anyone know where I can find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the doc in info format is not directly available.  However the texinfo file  (from wich the info file is generated) is included in the sources as `doc/gdb.texinfo`.  So if you install `gdb` from the sources, you should have the info file properly installed and accessible from emacs.

On debian systems, the documentation is not included in the `gdb` package but in the package `gdb-doc`.  Additionnaly, this package is in section "non-free" because the GNU Free Documentation License ([FDL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/fdl.html)) isn't compliant with the Debian Free Software Guidelines ([DFSG](https://www.debian.org/social_contract.en.html#guidelines)).

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I did in fact look for the texinfo file as well. With your answer I now know why I couldn't find either file (I'm on a Debian system).

Answer (score 0):

Upon reflection, this is a more general Linux question and should have been asked on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange. I found [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85417/some-info-pages-missing) there.